# Upgrading RAM on my desktop PC

Tags: memory, upgrade, desktop-computer, cache, ramdisk

I have recently brought a £40 desktop computer since I woke up and spilled coffee all over my old laptop.

I am learning to be a website developer and need to try and upgrade my RAM, so I can use image manipulation programs.

The computer I currently have is as follows:

- Hewlett-Packard 3646h version 786G7 v01.14
- Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU
- Package: Socket 775 LGA
- 4GB DDR3 Ram (Split between two sticks).

Searching on YouTube I just found a video that stated the maximum RAM 
I can have with an 775 LGA board is 8GB, The RAM That I have brought. Prior to watching this video is the Hyper X Fury 16GB (2 X 8GB sticks.) DDR3,

This [laptop spec website](http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/3646h-hewlett-packard-mainbaord-specifications/) states the maximum this motherboard can use is 16GB.

Will this be okay to just switch them out and change them? I am a complete novice when It comes to computer hardware and PC builds.

Also My Caches seem tiny, viewed in CPU-Z;

- L1D-cache: 32kb x 2
- L1I-cache: 32kb x 2
- L2-cache: 6144kb

these numbers seem miniscule considering I sometime have Firefox with 15-20 tabs open, plus Gimp or Photoshop and Sublime Text 3: Open all at the same time.

As a second question can I upgrade these also?

---

Update.
I have recieved the ram sticks & tried to install them on my desktop computer.
When trying to switch it on It bleeps at me the same as it would if you tried to start it with No Ram, Does anyone know if this specific motherboard is limited to a certain Ram Capacity or whther each ram slot has a limited capacity.
The Kingston HyperX Fury sticks that I am trying to install are UDimm & i think the old ones were just dimm Does this effect the funtionality...

Can anyone help. Do I need to change the clock speed of the cpu prior to installing the ram?

Using CPU-Z to view system stats The ram Currently in use is using 1.5 volts, which is the same voltage rating as the new ones.
So this is not an issue. But they are still not working.

Answer (score 0):

> This laptop spec website states the maximum this motherboard can use is 16GB.
>   Will this be okay to just switch them out and change them?

Usually, you can just put the modules in and see if they work. I have never witnessed any motherboard to be destroyed by putting in the wrong modules (rude methods aside), they just wouldn't work.

*However, as a disclaimer, I reject any responsibility in this regard. I merely state my own experience.*

> As a second question can I upgrade these [L1/L2 caches] also?

No.
Back in the days (of the Intel 386 processor) these caches were located on the motherboard. But that was a long time ago. Nowadays the caches are integrated into the CPU and you cannot upgrade them separately.

Answer (score -1):

Switching out the ram with the 16gb recommended will be a simple process. Once you have done this I would also upgrade the OS to the 64bit version if you haven't already.

A further and far more noticable upgrade would be to replace your old HDD with a Solid State Disk (SSD) - Then you would have a fairly decent machine in comparison to newer equipment.

You may also be able to upgrade the processor, but the difference would not be that great - This may also upgrade the caches.

I used a similar machine for years and the older HP desktops are some of the most reliable they have made.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm already running the 64bit version & I have a Hyper-X savage SSD, Thats part of the reason I brought the Fury RAM. Was Just Curious if the motherboard could handle 16GB also not sure if I have to change any timings etc as the RAM seems to be higher timings than my CPU

Comment: I Have manually Set my Pagefile to 6144MB so I can't see why CPU-Z is stating it as 6144KB